# mysql alter table won't work in php if column have incorrect values

Tags: php, mysql

i have a varchar column in my table. sometimes the column data could be empty, and sometimes it may contain some strange characters. so i'm trying to change the data type of the column to decimal 15,4.

so here's my php code

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE income CHANGE total total DECIMAL (15,4)", $db);
```

i run the code without any problem (no errors) but when i checked the table income, the datatype has not been changed to decimal. but when i run the query directly into mysql, the column would be successfully changed to decimal, but not without mysql displaying some warnings like

```
  Warning Code : 1292
Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''
```

but the point is, the datatype conversion is successful when I run the query directly in mysql (i'm using sqlyog), but not when i tried to run the query in php. any idea why? and how can I avoid this?

Comment: emm what do you mean by that?

Comment: `Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''` - Doesn't this indicate you are submitting empty strings?

Comment: Prix - because some of the values are not derived from user input, instead it is derived from calculations within the system. so I can't just round the values there and then

Comment: yup misterManSam,I'm aware of that. but my question is why is the query works when I run it directly in mysql, but not in php

Comment: Prix - nope doesn't work

Comment: Try `UPDATE income SET total = 0 WHERE total = ''` before your ALTER statement.

Comment: can't do that andrewtweber, since i need to keep the data intact, except for some of the misbehaving data

Comment: That **is** the misbehaving data. The error message is telling you that those rows can't be converted to DECIMAL because their values are invalid. You'll either have to change those values or delete the rows entirely. Also wouldn't `0` and `''` be equivalent in this case?

Comment: Have you tried changing `''` to `NULL` values beforehand …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with larger numbers (i.e. when selecting `LENGTH()`) the truncation does not happen when length `>65` but rather at >81,

and then gives a warning about **"Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''"** Which would have been incorrect already `>65`.

in your case you may have dealing with numbers hence length `>15`

EDIT: following your needs to make all values as decimal.

```
   UPDATE income SET total = CAST(total AS DECIMAL(15,4))
```

Comment: ermm... so what should I do?

Comment: litle difficult to say what you will do since you didnt show anything. you have already string data in your column and you converted column to decimal , delete your column and create otherone with new decimal values.

Comment: but why do the query works if i run it directly in mysql, but not in php?

Comment: have you tried when you select this `select CAST(total AS DECIMAL(15,4))` ?

Comment: echo_Me, the query you suggested runs well, but how is it related to converting the column's datatype from varchar to decimal? or can I integrate the query while converting the column's datatype? if yes, how should I do it?

Comment: @imin dude since your column have both decimal values which you inserted newly after changing column to decimal and have also varchar which you have them before converting table, so either remove table and insert all values in decimal , or use that query i gave you to handle the values which are varchar. there is other method also is to update all values by casting the values look my updated answer.